# How to run Apache Cassandra 3.x on Windows

Tags: windows, cassandra

I want to share my findings on how to run Apache Cassandra on Windows, because since 3.0 became available, the instructions are not easy to find for windows developers.

So here are the steps:

1.- Install Java 8 and configure JAVA_HOME env variable properly

2.- download tar.gz file from http://cassandra.apache.org/download/ and extract it into some local folder (i.e. c:\cassandra)

3.- you should set CASSANDRA_HOME env variable but it's not really required. You can go directly to your cassandra\bin folder and run cassandra.bat

Enjoy!

Comment: Very helpful , thx